# How to use Bootstrap5 with Vite and Nuxt3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-vue, vite, nuxtjs3

Tailwind makes it easy to use its CSS in projects set up with Vite as you can [see here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite).

However, Bootstrap 5 only has information available for using [with Webpack](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/webpack/).

I can not find anything about how to set Bootstrap 5 CSS with Vite. Does anyone have any tips on how to successfully and optimally set up Bootstrap 5 with Vite? I am using Nuxt3 but it should not matter which framework one uses.

Comment: Hi, what did you tried so far?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Variant 1.** Add it to `nuxt.config.ts`

```
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt'
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  app: {
    head: {
      link: [
        { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css', integrity: 'sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor', crossorigin: 'anonymous' }
      ],
      script: [
        { src: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js', integrity: 'sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2', crossorigin: 'anonymous' }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

Downside: needs manual version control, you can't use SASS features.

**Variant 2.**

1. Install bootstrap alongside @popperjs/core

```bash
yarn add bootstrap @popperjs/core
```

2. Create `plugins/useBootstrap.client.ts` file

```
import bootstrap from 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle'

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
  nuxtApp.provide('bootstrap', bootstrap)
})
```

No need to import it manually, since Nuxt3 will do it for you. Bootstrap JS should be available in your components/pages through

```
const { $bootstrap } = useNuxtApp()
```

3. Create `assets/styles/main.scss` file

```scss
@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

4. Add it to `nuxt.config.ts`

```
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt'

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  css: ['~/assets/styles/main.scss']
})
```

Comment: Is it possible to just import a single plugin instead of ALL of bootstrap JS plugins? For example, just want to use the Dropdown component.

Comment: for me all solutions are note working, for CSS ok but for js , nothing happen even if js is present, for example menu toggle collapse

Comment: With variant 2 I always get "Document is not defined"

Answer (score 2):

Now you can find the official words from bootstrap v5.2 Document

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/vite/

After install Nuxt3 this is official guide:

1- Install Vite. Unlike our Webpack guide, there’s only a single build tool dependency here. We use --save-dev to signal that this dependency is only for development use and not for production.

```
npm i --save-dev vite
```

2- Install Bootstrap. Now we can install Bootstrap. We’ll also install Popper since our dropdowns, popovers, and tooltips depend on it for their positioning. If you don’t plan on using those components, you can omit Popper here.

```
npm i --save bootstrap @popperjs/core
```

3- Install additional dependency. In addition to Vite and Bootstrap, we need another dependency (Sass) to properly import and bundle Bootstrap’s CSS

```
npm i --save-dev sass
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, you should also include the essential parts into the answer itself. Link-only answers usually get deleted. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33746887)

Comment: sorry, I edit my answer to add new extra info thanks @tdy

Answer (score 0):

You can import JavaScript plugins individually as needed to keep bundle sizes down:

```
import Alert from 'bootstrap/js/dist/alert';
```

or, specify which plugins you need:

```
import { Tooltip, Toast, Popover } from 'bootstrap';
```

Comment: Not sure this works becasue some of the jS components such as the modal and drop down will break on SSR, thus need to set it up as a plugin using the `.client` format extension.