# Nuxt3 and Bootstrap 5 Dropdown: Document is not defined error

Tags: vuejs3, bootstrap-5, nuxtjs3

Is it possible to use the [**Bootstrap 5 dropdown component**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/dropdowns/) in a Nuxt 3 app?

My attempt failed with the following error:

`[nuxt] [request error] document is not defined`

Thus, I tried to wrap the dropdown component in a `<ClientOnly>` component but that did not help.

Anyone got a suggestion on how I can get the dropdown to work?

Here's my code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-4jphlx?file=components/Dropdown.vue

`App.vue`:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <ClientOnly>
     <Dropdown />
    </ClientOnly>
  </div>
</template>
```

`Dropdown.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button
      class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle"
      type="button"
      id="dropdownMenuButton1"
      data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
      aria-expanded="false"
    >
      Dropdown button
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import Dropdown from 'bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown.js';
</script>
```

Comment: You should wrap your dropdown inside a component and wrap that component inside the `ClientOnly` component

Comment: This one doesn't work? https://stackoverflow.com/a/67751550/8816585

Comment: Still get `document not defined` when wrapping dropdown component in ClientOnly tag. I'll try the other possible solutions, @kissu

Comment: Doing it this way worked! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71795143/how-to-use-bootstrap5-with-vite-and-nuxt3